# Android findViewById for toolbar returning null

Tags: java, android, xml, android-toolbar, findviewbyid

In my android app, I'm using a custom toolbar, and the `findViewById()` can't seem to find the toolbar.

I've looked around the internet at all the similar problems to this one, and none of them seemed to work.

My screen always returns the Toast "Toolbar Failed..."

Here's my java `onCreate()`:

```
protected Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        if(toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Toolbar failed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(Home.this,"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
            }
        }

    }
```

Here's the xml layout file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/home"
            android:layout_below="@id/tool_bar"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your Scripture:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scripturecontainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="You have not selected a scripture yet..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="trywidget"
        android:text="Try the Widget"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scripturecontainer"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/widget_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="change"
        android:text="Select A Scripture"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="suggest"
        android:text="Suggest A Feature"
        android:layout_below="@+id/widget_button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="wallpaper"
        android:text="Change the Wallpaper"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here's my style xml file:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the layout you're setting for that `Activity`, since it doesn't have a `ViewGroup` with ID `container`, and that `FragmentTransaction` would cause a crash without that when first run.

Comment: It doesn't crash. Just returns a null.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "returns a null", but that `FragmentTransaction` would crash if the current layout didn't have `container`. Given that, and the fact that `findViewById()` is returning `null` for your `Toolbar`, I would say that the layout you've posted is not `activity_home`.

Comment: The layout I've posted is fragment_home. There is an activity_home.xml too.

Comment: These are the kinds of things you need to specify in your question. Anyway, you're looking for the `Toolbar` in the `Activity` before it has loaded the `Fragment`, so it's not going to find it. Since the Toolbar is in the `Fragment`, you should be finding and handling it in the `Fragment`.

Comment: Should I move the toolbar to the activity? Or if not, how do I write code for the fragment?

Comment: It depends on what your design is. If you want the `Toolbar` always in the `Activity`, then yeah, it should be in the `Activity`'s layout.

Comment: This worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
             android:id="@+id/toolbar"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
             android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
             app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Use above code to declare toolbar in your xml and change the

> ```
> android:theme="your_theme"
> ```

Comment: This just returned an exception that said that it couldn't find the view android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.

Comment: @sub6resources Then you are missing `compile "com.android.support:design:23.2.1"` in your build.gradle